# "test" text is become "tes" in wpf textblock

Tags: wpf, textblock

I am working on WPF application.
when I am testing this I provide textblock text "test" in coding and goes to output it displays only "tes", instead this text/word ("test"), all text working fine, like if I provide "test1", it displays "test1".
can anyone tell me, why this is so ?

Comment: Please share the piece of code that you have written.. that will be helpful. Or the ASPX tag.. Thanks

Comment: <TextBlock Text="test"
HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="lblUserName" FontSize="16" />
--it is also displaying "tes". please suggest

Comment: can you please share the small screenshot of both the cases in the main question. That will be more helpful.

Comment: you gotta be doing something with your textbox. what are you doing with it exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many question here where users say 'hey, this doesn't work', when really, all they need to do is look at their code. You gave us some code (which you really should have added to your question for clarity):

```
<TextBlock Text="test" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
    Name="lblUserName" FontSize="16" />
```

If, instead of coming to this site, creating a new user and asking a question, you had simply put your own code into a new project or `Window`, then you would see that it works just fine... try it now. :)

As such, like @devhedgehog said, you must have something else in your code that is cutting off the end of your `TextBlock`. A good way to find the offending element is set the `Background` properties of your various controls:

```
<TextBlock Text="test" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
    Name="lblUserName" FontSize="16" Background="Red" />
```

Using this, it should be clear that the `TextBlock` has been cut off. If you set this property on the other controls on your page then you should eventually find the one that is covering or restricting the size of your `TextBlock`.

It *could* also be getting cut off by a containing `Grid Column` or `StackPanel` if you have not set the `Width` correctly.